# Upgrading my notebook's CPU to one more powerful yet more power consuming

Tags: laptop, cpu, motherboard, power-consumption

I have a hardware question.

My notebook is a [Dell Inspiron 1470](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Dell-Inspiron-1470.25601.0.html). I'd like to upgrade my CPU from the [original one](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Pentium+SU4100+%40+1.30GHz&id=599) to a [more powerful one](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Core2+Duo+SP9400+%40+2.40GHz&id=978) but I wonder if the significantly bigger power consumption is a problem. I was looking for info about that but I didn't find anything. The only information I was able to find out is the wattage of my power supply, which is 65W.

I found this stronger CPU from list of [compatible socket CPUs](http://www.cpu-world.com/Related_CPUs/BGA956_Core.html) to mine.

So the question is: will my notebook burn or is it safe what I am planning to do?

Comment: Your original CPU uses socket  BGA956. BGA is ball grid array. That usually means soldered onto the motherboard, so getting it replaced without damaging anything is **hard**. After that you run into the potential problems as mentioned by duskwuff, more power used, more heat generated. Firmware (e.g. BIOS of UEFI should be new enough to understand the new CPU). Probably fun to test as a hobby project, but it probably would take a lot of work with specialised equipment and at that time you want to compare time/cost and chance at success vs a low end modern laptop.

Comment: @Hennes Thanks for pointing out that these were BGA parts -- I've added that (very important!) detail to my answer.

Comment: The question about upgrading laptop CPUs keeps popping up.  At root access we just discussed a canonical post as an option. Feel free participate.

Answer (score 3):

Information on these processors is available at [ark.intel.com](https://ark.intel.com/), Intel's product specifications site.

The [Pentium SU4100](https://ark.intel.com/products/43568/Intel-Pentium-Processor-SU4100-2M-Cache-1_30-GHz-800-MHz-FSB) has a TDP (thermal design power) of 10W.

The [Core 2 Duo SP9400](https://ark.intel.com/products/36693/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-SP9400-6M-Cache-2_40-GHz-1066-MHz-FSB) has a TDP of 25W.

What's most important, though, is that these are both BGA parts ("Sockets Supported: BGA956"). They are soldered to the circuit board of your laptop, and cannot be installed or removed without specialized equipment.

Even if you had some way of swapping the processors, the SP9400 uses ~2.5x more power, and generates ~2.5x more heat, than the SU4100. It is highly unlikely that your laptop would be able to deliver enough power to run this processor, or be able to keep it at an appropriate temperature under load.

Given that this is a 8-10 year old laptop, it's probably best that you simply replace it with a newer model.

Comment: I didn't know about processors being soldered into motherboard but still I don't think it would be so much of a trouble for me - I am familiar with soldering and I have semi-pro equipment so I could try my chances.

What I am concerned about though is the power supplied by my motherboard. As you said: "It is highly unlikely that your laptop would be able to deliver enough power to run this processor". I'd like to determine how much power do I have to spend. In PCs it's easy - just open it and read from power unit but how do I know in notebook?